# unexpected text from the NFC tag

Tags: android, kotlin, nfc

I am making a app with NFC first time.
In my tag I have got data MimeType record type ( application/json
Data: "My text" ).

This is my code:

```
private fun processIntent(checkIntent: Intent) {

    if (checkIntent.action == NfcAdapter.ACTION_NDEF_DISCOVERED) {

        // pobieranie wiadomości NDEF z taga NFC
        val rawMessages = checkIntent.getParcelableArrayExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_NDEF_MESSAGES)

        // wiadomość NDEF zawiera wszystkie rekordy z tagu NFC
        var ndefMsg = rawMessages[0] as NdefMessage

        // pojedynczy 1 rekord z tagu NFC ( indeks 0 to 1 rekord, indeks 1 to 2 rekord itd. )
        var ndefRecord = ndefMsg.records[0]

        // jeśli 1 rekord nie jest pusty to pobierz PAYLOAD ( dane ) i wyświetl go
        // jeśli 1 rekord jest pusty wyświetl błąd
        if(ndefRecord.toMimeType() != null)
        {
            Log.v("processIntent", ndefRecord.payload.toString())
            var payload = ndefRecord.payload.toString()


            textView.text = payload
            var i = 2
        }
        else
        {
            Log.e("processIntent", "ERROR A1")
        }

    }
}
```

In LogCat I have got this:

```
V/processIntent: [B@82162f9
```

How I can make a my text message from this ( Should be "My text" )?

Comment: Try this

Log.v("processIntent", ndefRecord.payload)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, `ndefRecord.payload` is a `ByteArray`, so what you're seeing is the default printout of an `Object` type (`[B` for byte array; `@82162f9` for the memory address).

You'll need to convert it to a `String`. This depends on how the tag data is encoded which will be up to the tag creator. However, assuming it's either UTF-8 or ASCII, you can just use the `String` constructor:

```
val payloadString = String(ndefRecord.payload, StandardCharsets.US_ASCII)
val payloadString = String(ndefRecord.payload, StandardCharsets.UTF_8)
```

Answer (score 0):

for example:

```
if (rawMessages != null) {
    val messages = arrayOfNulls<NdefMessage?>(rawMessages.size)
    for (i in rawMessages.indices) {
        messages[i] = rawMessages[i] as NdefMessage;
    }         
    processNdefMessages(messages)
}
```

and:

```
private fun processNdefMessages(ndefMessages: Array<NdefMessage?>) {
    for (curMsg in ndefMessages) {
        if (curMsg != null) {

            logMessage("Message", curMsg.toString())
            logMessage("Records", curMsg.records.size.toString())

            for (curRecord in curMsg.records) {
                if (curRecord.toUri() != null) {
                    logMessage("- URI", curRecord.toUri().toString())
                } else {
                    logMessage("- Contents", curRecord.payload.contentToString())
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```